# Several instances of a @Singleton OpenEJB bean present

Tags: java, singleton, testng, openejb

I have a class which looks like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MySingletonImpl implements MySingleton{
    @Override
    public void init(){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void test(){
        ...
    }

}
```

It is called from the `ApplicationComposer` `testng` test which looks like this:

```
@Listeners(ApplicationComposerListener.class)
public class MyTest{
     @EJB
     MySingleton mySingleton;

     @Module
     @Classes(cdi=true, value={MySingletonImpl.class})
     public EjbModule ejbModule() throws Exception{
          return new EjbModule(new EjbJar());
     }

     @BeforeClass
     public void setup(){
          mySingleton.init();
     }

     @Test
     public void test(){
          mySigleton.test();
     }
}
```

The problem I observe when the test runs, is that the `object id` of the instance of `MySingletonImpl` class that the `test()` method  called on is not the same as the instance on which the `init()` method is called.

The behavior seems strange.

First, how my problem can be fixed? I want to init and then call methods on the same object, not different instances of the same class.

Second, why at all would the container instantiate multiple `@Singleton`s?

Answer (score 1):

Is your interface is @Remote or local? If its @Local change it to @Remote:

> "EJB specification doesn’t guarantee any behaviour when 
>     you use the local business interfaces for inter-modules 
>     communication even if those modules are part of the 
>     same Application Server / JVM."

https://coderanch.com/mobile/t/608212/java/instances-Singleton-EJB

Comment: I suppose my application does not feature inter-module communication, though I'm a little confused as to what considered a "module". When testing, ApplicationComposer is supposed to create a single module, as is suggested by the Module annotation. When running, the application is deployed as a single war having one web.xml, with several jars, each one with it's beans.xml descriptor. As far as I can tell, it's considered one "module". I'd like to avoid making the interface Remote, to prevent serialization-deserialization penalty and complications. Thanks.